# ERROR while querying data on redshift - Error fetching stripe data

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to run the following query over an external table in redshift:

```
select * from schema.table limit 10;
```

and I get an error:

> [2018-06-20 12:03:14] [XX000][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
>   Details:
>   error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
>   code:      15001
>   context:   Task failed due to an internal error. Error fetching stripe data from ORC file https://s3/XXXXXX.orc File size

when I query the same files in athena it works fine. There are more tables in the schema and I can query them as usual.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, please update the thread if you have the solution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, this means that either one of the files is corrupted or there is an issue fetching the file from S3. Please have a look at the [svl_s3log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_S3LOG.html) view to see if you can extract the last part of the message. From what I can see it might be that you have a text file in between the ORC files?

Comment: Thanks, in the error table in redshift it had the full exception - the files were too small.